# How to prevent redirection when drag an anchor bound ‘mousedowd, mousemove, mouseup’?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a draggable image.

BUT `<img>` is wrapped by `<a>`

```
<a href="http://somewhere.com">
  <img src="someone.png"/>
</a>
```

I bind 'mousedown, mousemove, mouseup' on the anchor to implement draggale.
But when 'mouseup', it will redirect.

**How to prevent redirection if it was dragged?**

P.S. I tried to add event.preventDefault() into mouseup handler, but it doesn't work.

CODE IN DETAIL:

```
$('.item').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    // if not using preventDefault(), image won't move when 'mousemove'
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.item').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        // update 'left' and 'top'
    });
});

$('.item').on('mouseup', function () {

    // still redirect !?!?
    return false
});
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you realize you've misspelt preventDefault(), so if that is actually the code...could be a problem...

Comment: I'm sorry, I am China, it was 1 am, and I was so tired. The code above is just a short version of mine, but I'm pretty SURE, I didn't misspelt in my real code. `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: i don't see the item class in your html. really need to see exactly what you have in order to figure out what may be going wrong.

Comment: thanks any way, I finally fix this problem by sharing a 'draged' variable with 'mousemove' and 'click' event. Unfortunately, I'm inside GFW, and cannot upload my code to jsfiddle or somewhere for you to check. Thank you.

Comment: Just to check - are you unbinding things afterwards? It's a big memory leak otherwise. With touch support : http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/ZYbWzL?editors=001

Answer (score 1):

`preventDefault` prevents the default event for a mouseup on the dragable image, but the event is then propagated to the enclosing <a> tag which has its own default behavior. You'll need to stop event propagation so that the event isn't sent to the link in case of a drag/drop. EDIT: as mentioned by TrueBlueAussie in the comments, it's the `click` event that triggers the link. That's the event which must be blocked from reaching the link.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Preventing `mouseup` propagation will not stop a ancestor link from firing. You need to stop the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question as I've never seen this in the MouseUp Event. What I'd do is just

> return false;

from your mouseup handler, like this:

```
$("#anchor").on("click",function(){
  //do some mouseup stuff
  console.log("Doing mouseup stuff");
  return false;
});
```

Here is a Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/59ddut6s/3/

I think the `event.stopPropagation();` mentioned by Jacque could be a better solution, but it's definitely not what I would typically think to do myself.

UPDATE: Minor change based on comments. Some useful info down there worth reading. I didn't consider that this method would case both `event.stopPropogation()` and `event.preventDefault()` but it makes sense that it would.

What still confuses me is WHY would on("click") prevent the link from navigating, but not on("mouseup")?

Comment: Seems it does not work in my case.
I implement draggable by update item's 'left' and 'top', I update my problem above, please help.

Comment: Note: `return false` from an event handler causes both `e.preventDefault()` *and* `e.stopPropagation()` so if it does not work something else is amiss.

Comment: Also note: cancelling `mouseup` will not stop the anchor from firing. You need to stop `click` to do that (your JSFiddle does not work). Using alert in the middle of a mouse event handler is going to give really unpleasant results. Use `console.log` instead :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for your insights. I've made some updates, but actually have a question of my own (bottom of answer). Wonder if I should post it. Found a similar question, but doesn't really answer this.